# Gain iOS root access

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I don't know is this is possible, but can I change stock iOS files? More specifically, I wan't  to edit the file "SystemVersion.plist" in "/System/Library/CoreServices/" and I use NSDictionary. This is how my code looks like:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSArray *array;
fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

[fm changeCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/System/Library/CoreServices/"];
array = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:fm.currentDirectoryPath error:NULL];
NSLog(@"Path:%@ Items:%@", fm.currentDirectoryPath, array);

NSDictionary *systemVersion = [[NSDictionary alloc]  initWithContentsOfFile:@"SystemVersion.plist"];
[systemVersion setValue:@"7.0" forKey:@"ProductVersion"];
[systemVersion writeToFile:@"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist" atomically:NO]; //This code doesn't overwrite the current file!
```

I've looked all over the internet, and not found an answer! I hope that I'm left with no choice than jailbreaking

UPDATE:
Is it better that I ask then how I can gain root access from c or objective-c?

Comment: think about it for a bit... if you could modify system files, you could have control of the device. ios is about removing as much control as possible from the user. locking someone in jail isn't much point if every prison cell has a hacksaw and blowtorch provided as standard issue.

Comment: This is definitely impossible for App Store apps and non-jailbroken devices.

Comment: I didn't mean publish to the app-store, I meant for personal use. Well, I guess there's no way :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done using public API and I doubt that there is an easy to use private API.

But there certainly are exploitable security issues that allow programs to gain root access. Without those jailbreaking would not be possible at all. So if you really want root access you should study how jailbreaks are done. This is not going to be easy.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, I'll look around how JB:ing is done